# How to resize CSS Box with increase in content

Tags: html, css, box

I have created a CSS Box for my navigation bar. When I add new items in the navigation bar or viewed with lower resolution, the new item jumps to the next line. But, the box does not increase in size and remain absolute.

Could not post image due to lack of reputation. So, here is the link for images

Image 1: Navigation bar in 1366px width resolution
Link: http://i19.servimg.com/u/f19/15/84/74/16/110.png

Image 2: Navigation bar in 1024x width resolution
Link: http://i19.servimg.com/u/f19/15/84/74/16/210.png

```css
body{
    /* Setting the default text color, size, page background and a font stack: */
    background:#ebebeb;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Trebuchet, 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:87.5%;
    color:#7d7d7d;
    line-height: 1.429;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 70%;
}

.mainHeader {
    clear: both;
    overflow:auto;
}

#logo {
    float:left;
}

#logo figcaption{
    visibility: hidden;
}


/*************************
******* NAVIGATION *******
**************************/

nav {
    margin: 90px 5px 10px 5px;
    padding: 8px;
    height: 60px; 
    width: auto;
    font-size: 1.143em;
    line-height: 90px;
    text-align: center;

    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
}

.mainHeader nav ul {
    list-style: none; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.mainHeader nav ul li {
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: left; 
    display: inline; 
}

nav ul li:nth-of-type(1){
    background-image: url('http://islington.ml/images/navigation/activeHome.png');
    background-size: 40%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
}
nav ul li:nth-of-type(2){
    background-image: url('http://islington.ml/images/navigation/courses.png');
    background-size: 40%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
}
nav ul li:nth-of-type(3){
    background-image: url('http://islington.ml/images/navigation/lectures.png');
    background-size: 40%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
}
nav ul li:nth-of-type(4){
    background-image: url('http://islington.ml/images/navigation/admission.png');
    background-size: 40%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
}
nav ul li:nth-of-type(5){
    background-image: url('http://islington.ml/images/navigation/facilities.png');
    background-size: 40%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
}
nav ul li:nth-of-type(6){
    background-image: url('http://islington.ml/images/navigation/contact.png');
    background-size: 40%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
}

.mainHeader nav a:link{
    padding: 5px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold; 
}
```

```html
     <body>
         <header class="mainHeader">
            <figure id="logo">
                <img src="http://islington.ml/images/logo.png" alt="Islington College Logo">
                <figcaption>ISLINGTON</figcaption>
            </figure> 
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" style="color: #EE2B32;">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lectures</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Admission</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Facilities</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
            </nav>
        <header>
    </body>
```

Comment: Use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries).

Comment: Use `min-height:60px` instead of `height:60px`

Comment: Also, add a clearfix ( `<div style="clear:both;"></div>`) just before `</nav>`. This will force the container to expand with the content.

Comment: @Sachink - he would need a few more changes on top of that to make it look the same.

Comment: @codyogden, using min-height or (height: auto) and div clear; both solved the problem, but it gives unnecessary height for inital single line nav bar.

Comment: @remonray Have you tried using `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left` for everything? That would reduce the number of items you're throwing out of the DOM flow and would expand the container automatically.